# Jquery mobile listview and media queries

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I have a list view:

```
<ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="nav" role="navigation" data-icon="none" data-corners="false">
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
```

With the following css media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
    .ui-corner-top {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .ui-corner-bottom {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

} /* end media query */
```

What's *supposed* to happen is when the user views the listview on a smaller screen, the rounded corners turn into square corners.

However, this seems to work well in Chrome, but not Safari or an iPhone. In fact, if I use Firebug lite on Safari, it looks like the style isn't even showing up (but it shows up in the Chrome developer's toolbar)...?

Comment: Have you used viewport tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>, Safari requires it? Also what happens when you change max-width to max-device-width and can set it to 480px?

Comment: Why not make use of the `orientationchange` events to change the class of the list view?

Comment: @ Gajotres yup I have that meta tag in place already.